# What is the song that plays when Midoriya is explaining the origin of heroes in season 2?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the name of the instrumental that plays in the majority of the season 2 intro scenes when Midoriya is explaining the origin of heroes?

It's in season 2 episode 3 at the very beginning before the opening theme song plays. It sounds more like a choir/alternate version of *I Am Here*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song is called "Avant Title" in the second season original soundtrack! I was looking everywhere for it too. It's so beautiful, my heart is about to burst :D

Answer (score 0):

You must be talking about  ***Watashi ga kita***

Find a youtube link to it [here](https://youtu.be/FYy_QS0xKBA)

***Edit:***

Got you buddy. As you mentioned episode 3 of season 2.
It is one of the variations of the *All Might* theme. Updated my answer. :-)

Comment: I love You Can Become a Hero but that's not the song I am talking about. It sounds more like a choir/alternate version of I Am Here but I can't find it anywhere